# How are reference to objects handled in javascript when returning object and modifying them in their original functions

Tags: javascript, function, scope, reference

I am trying to create a function that returns an object and a function that reset this object to its initial state. Something like:

```js
const create = () => ({
    a: "something"
});

const setup = () => {
    let obj = create();

    const reset = () => {
        obj = create();
    }

    return {
        obj,
        reset
    }
}

const { reset, obj: myObj } = setup();

myObj.b = 2;
reset();
console.log("expected to be undefined", myObj.b);
```

But when I call the function and uses the reset function, it doesn't reset the object. `myObj.2` still contains `2`. I expected the reference to `myObj` to stay the same, so when we call `reset` obj becomes a new object and myObj's reference points to that new object.

After some fiddling around I realized that my function works if I do this instead:

```js
const create = () => ({
    a: "something"
});

const setupWithGet = () => {
    let obj = create();

    const getObj = () => obj;

    const reset = () => {
        obj = create();
    }

    return {
        getObj,
        reset
    }
}

const { reset, getObj } = setupWithGet();

getObj().b = 2;
reset();
console.log("expected to be undefined", getObj().b);
```

Why do I need to use a new function here?

Comment: `obj` contains a reference to the object A. `myObj` contains a copy of `obj` with a reference to object A. `reset` creates an object B and changes `obj`, but it can't change `myObj`. You get two different references to two different objects A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned by `setup()` contains a reference to the original value of `obj`. When you reassign `obj` it doesn't change this reference, it still refers to the original object. It's not linked to the variable in any way.

You don't need any of the methods or scope issues to demonstrate this. See the simple code here:

```js
let obj = {a: "something"};
let container = {obj};
console.log(container);
obj = {a: "something else"};
console.log(container);
```

Reassigning `obj` has no effect on the `container` object. Its reference is to the original value of `obj`.

In your second version, `getObj` is a closure that references the local variable `obj`, not the object. Reassigning the variable updates the variable in that scope, and the function returns that new value.

Comment: I guess my confusion comes the fact that the object returned by `setup()` contains a reference to the original value instead of a reference to the `obj` variable, is it because `obj` is scoped to `setup` function so it is impossible to access `obj` from outside the function hence why it returns a copy?

Comment: I've added more information to the answer, does that help?

Comment: If you're familiar with languages like C, references are like pointers. If you have two pointers to the same value, and you change one of the pointers, it doesn't change the other pointer.

Comment: Yes it's clearer now, thanks for your help!